# Can you get an explicit skeleton out of a gltf file?

Tags: c++, animation, graphics, gltf, skinning

For debugging purposes I want to render the skeleton of a skinned mesh. However, in glTF they seem to be defined in a very abstract way. That is to say, there is no "skeleton" as in, a set of vertices connected by lines. In other words this is not explicitly defined:
[image]

Instead the "skeleton" is actually a collection of nodes that only specify matrices that convert the positions of the relevant vertices into the position of the joint.

Is it nonetheless possible to extract where the joint is? Maybe through inverting the inverseBindmatrix or something like that?

TL;DR I have a gltf model, I wanna render the skeleton of it like in blender.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure you're not looking for a "mostly" or "kinda-sorta" answer here, but indeed there are some complicating factors.

I'll start with the basic strategy:  glTF is a last-mile format, a GPU-ready format designed to get data pumped into rendering APIs with minimal fuss.  As such, glTF has no compassion for "artist asset interchange" type features that would be meaningless to an end-user client.  And in this case, we have a casualty of that philosophy: The bone's length.

The bone's origin and orientation are well-known.  They are (typically empty) nodes in the glTF scene hierarchy, and indeed we only know they count as "bones" when a skin comes along with a list of joints, that indicate which nodes are actually bones.  Being a glTF node means that the bone has a known relationship to its parent, in the form of a transformation matrix, or more likely, in the form of translate, rotate, and scale parameters on the node.  This gives you the bone's origin and orientation.  It can even be animated, just like any glTF node can have an animation applied (but only when using TRS, not with the matrix).

But the length of the bone isn't needed in glTF.  Why not?  Because for the sake of getting the model rendered quickly, what's needed is the bone's influence over the surrounding vertices.  This is done with the `JOINTS_0` and `WEIGHTS_0` accessors (vertex attributes), so each vertex knows which bones can influence it, and by how much.  The "length" of the bone is a useful visualization parameter for artists, but is not needed in the vertex shader to calculate where the skin ended up.  A given 3D app may use the bone length to help calculate or seed the vertex joint weights, but once those are calculated, they can be hand-tweaked and changed, and the original bone length is moot.

The inverseBindMatrix essentially holds the bind pose.  It is the inverse of the bone's original rest/bind position relative to the root (not parent).  Take that arm bone for example, it has some non-zero +X position.  But when it sits there in its own rest position, it should have essentially no effect on the skin, it shouldn't be pulling the skin further +X from where it originally was.  The fact that the arm bone is away from the model's origin makes it want to pull other vertices further away, and the inverseBindMatrix is there to un-do that effect.  So when the bone is at rest (in the bind pose), the bone and its inverseBindMatrix will cancel each other out perfectly.  As the bone starts to move away from that pose, it starts to exert influence.

For what it's worth, the Blender glTF importer has some fancy shenanigans to make a best-effort guess at the bone length when importing a glTF.  But it also imports the raw vertex weights, so, the bone length is merely for the artist's visual benefit, it has no effect on the skin.

Comment: There something here that confuses me. There has to be a way to extract the positions of the nodes relative to the root, because in order to specify a transformation relative to a node  you need to put things in that nodes reference frame.

i.e. the matrices should implicitly have the change of basis matrix multiplied witht hem, which in turn should specify the relative offset from the root. Or am I wrong?

Comment: That's true, yes. You can get the root end of each bone without inspecting skinning weights or IBMs, it's just the world position of the joint node. And then for each non-leaf joint, the other end of the bone would just be the position of the next joint in the chain. That would be enough to display the skeleton for debugging purposes. But the concept of bone "length" does not exist independently, as emackey explains above.

Comment: If you're wondering how to get the world position of a given node, here's an example: https://github.com/donmccurdy/glTF-Transform/blob/5c35405d28e5e7638ef55e502aa12347a3ce6427/packages/core/src/properties/node.ts#L129-L146 ... this computes the world matrix for the node, which could be decomposed into world position.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following logic:

- Joint node position in world is bone start point
- If joint node has children, child node position in world is bone end point, and bone length is distance from start to end.
- Else if joint node has parent, bone length is distance to parent
- Else use constant bone length

In theory you could go through vertex position data and use maximum distance from joint node position to vertex as bone length.